# How to generate or change HostPath in kubernetes config for each developer?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, helm, minikube

In Kubernetes, you can create a volume to mount into a with **hostpath**.

This **hostPath** should provide a directory on the node running the pod. It's useful when you are working in development environments using minikube, we use this **hostPath** to sync code (per example)

```
 ...
 volumes:
      - name: source
        hostPath:
          path: /Users/fermin/project/wopwop
 ...
```

That path could be different for each developer (path: /Users/<your-name)/project/wopwop).

My first approximation was a *brute force method*, replace with a shell script <WORK_DIR> by a ENV variable $WORK_DIR where its value could be like `WORK_DIR=/Users/fermin/project`.

Any ideas to do this in a better way? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into OpenShift? This kubernetes descendant provides much better separation between different users and projects.

Comment: Kubernetes fits with all the project, this is the only config pain in dev environments. Nowadays I don't consider other solutions. But I will study openshift for the future

Comment: take a look to skaffold

Comment: All developers are using a single minikube cluster or each dev has it's own minilube cluster? I'm asking because with minikube you can mount a local directory: `minikube start --mount-string="$HOME/go/src/github.com/nginx:/data"`